# Solr Spring boot application failed to run, giving bean error

Tags: java, spring-boot, solr, lucene, full-text-search

Getting an error while running , a solr spring boot application, it says

"Parameter 0 of constructor in Controller required a bean of type Repository that could not be found."

"Consider defining a bean of type Repository in your configuration."

Here is my enitiy

```
@SolrDocument(collection = "content_core")
public class ContentDoc {
@Id
@Indexed
private String id;

@Indexed(name = "display_title", type = "string")
private String displayTitle;
}
```

Here is my solr config file

```
@EnableSolrRepositories(basePackages = "com.baeldung.repository.ContentDocRepository.spring.data.solr.repository", namedQueriesLocation = "classpath:solr-named-queries.properties")
@ComponentScan
public class SolrConfig {
@Bean
public SolrClient solrClient() {
return new HttpSolrClient.Builder("http://localhost:8983/solr").build();
}

@Bean
public SolrTemplate solrTemplate(SolrClient client) throws Exception {
return new SolrTemplate(client);
}
}
```

Here is my controller

```
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/content")
@AllArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class ContentDocController {

private final ContentDocRepository contentDocRepository;

@GetMapping("/searchfaq")
public Map<String, Object> searchFaq(@RequestParam("sectionId") Long sectionId,
@RequestParam("seachTerm") String searchTerm) {

// ContentDoc contentDoc = new ContentDoc();
// contentDoc.setContentId((long)1);
// contentDoc.setDisplayTitle("virat");
// contentDocRepository.save(contentDoc);
return null;
}
}
```

Here is my repository

```
@Qualifier("contentDocRepository")
public interface ContentDocRepository extends SolrCrudRepository<ContentDoc, String> {
public List<ContentDoc> findByName(String displayTitle);
}
```

this is the error that I am getting ->

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-10-20 18:22:47.836 ERROR 2760 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

*********
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
*********

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.aa.aa.controller.ContentController required a bean of type 'com.aa.aa.repository.ContentDocRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.aa.aa.repository.ContentDocRepository' in your configuration.
```

I am trying to create an an api which searches data from DB , and using solr to index the db data.

I am following this page -> https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-solr

Comment: Could you add the entire exception stack trace?

Comment: @VitalyChura added the entire error